# Embedded flash .swf interactivity broken on css scale of the parent

Tags: html, css, flash, transform

I am trying to add a `swf` object into the html page. It has lot of user interactivities. It works fine by default. There is an option in the page where the user can zoom in/out the entire page. I am applying `css` `transform` property to scale the entire parent `div`.

```
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
```

After scaling, the swf is zoomed out But i cant interact with the object. I cant click on any buttons, cant enter any text.

Is there a way to fix this. i am totally struck here.

Comment: Any reason of using HTML transform when you are using flash and can build in flash itself??

Comment: @NathanLee My main app is a ebook reader. Reader has got the zoom functionality. So yes i really need the html transform.

Comment: Do you have an example we can look at?